# Finding inverse of a composite function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse

Let $f (x) = x^{3}+x$ and $g (x) =x^{3} -x$ for all x.

I have to find derivative of $g\circ f^{-1}$ at $x=2$.

My textbook did this:

$(g \circ f^{-1})' (2) = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g \circ f^{-1}(2 + h) - g \circ f^{-1}(2)}{h}$

$ = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(1 + \frac{h}{4}) - g(1)}{h}$

$= \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(1 + \frac{3h}{4}) - (1 + \frac{h}{4}) - 0}{h} $

$= \dfrac{1}{2}$

Can anyone please explain second step?

Answer (score 2):

$f'(2)=4$, so $\bigl(f^{-1}\bigr)'\bigl(f^{-1}(2)\bigr)=\dfrac{1}{4}$. Btw, there's a typo at the beginning of the formula: it's $\bigl(g\circ f^{-1}\bigr)'(2)$ that is being computed.

More generally, you can prove that 
$$\bigl(g\circ f^{-1}\bigr)'(x)=\dfrac{g'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)}{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)
}. $$

Indeed, the chain rule results in$$\Bigl(g\circ f^{-1}\Bigr)'(x)= g'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)\cdot\bigl(f^{-1}\bigr)'(x)= g'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)\cdot\frac{1}{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)} $$
since $\bigl( f^{-1}\bigr)'(x)= \dfrac{1}{f'(y)}$, where $f(y)=x$.

Comment: F inverse at 2 =4 why

Comment: You misread what I wrote: it's the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $2$  that's equal to 4. Actually,  $f^{-1}(2)=1$.

Comment: Do ihave to find $f^{-1} $ for this

Comment: I don't think so. It would use Cardano's method. Here $1$ is an evident root of $x^3+x=2$.

Comment: How do you know that there is exists an isomorphism between $f$ and $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @Bernard Can you please explain in detail

Comment: @Alex Silva: What do you mean exactly? There's no isomorphism here.

Comment: @Bernard,  For a $x_0$, Has $y^3 + y = x_0$ always a unique solution?

Comment: @Bernard How have you calculated derivative of f inverse without computing it

Comment: @Jessica Gtb: The derivative $f'(x)$ of a function $f$ and the derivative $\bigl(f^{-1}\bigr)'(f(x))$ of its inverse function are inverse to each other, provided that the former is not zero. Then just replace $x$ with $f^{-1}(x)$. Is that clear?

Comment: @Bernard i am not geting the point

Comment: But you stil have to calculate f inverse so that you could replace

Comment: In general, you would. In the case of $2$, you don't since you *know* $f^{-1}(2)=1$.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation  are you using this formula given beneath figure

Comment: @Jessica Gfb: Absolutely.

Comment: Are you sure about your general formula? What happens if you substitute $f(x)$ for $x$? I think the denominator must be $f'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)$ instead of $\left(f^{-1}\right)'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)$

Comment: @Bernard can you provide glory details for this question , its difficult for me

Comment: @drhab: Ooops! Did some drag'n drop not to have to retype a whole formula and forgot to change some details. Corrected now.

Comment: @Jessica Gtb: I added some ddetails – more or less in the lines of drhab

Comment: @Alex Silva: Oh! You meant f is a bijection! $f$ is the sum of two (strictly) increasing, continuous functions, hence is itself strictly increasing and continuous, hence is a bijection from its domain onto its image – $\mathbf R$, as follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @Bernard, I saw this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using $f^{-1}\circ f=\operatorname{id}$ and applying the chainrule we find:
$$g'\left(x\right)=\left(g\circ f^{-1}\circ f\right)'\left(x\right)=\left(g\circ f^{-1}\right)'\left(f\left(x\right)\right)f'\left(x\right)$$

Divide by $f'(x)$ to achieve: $$\left(g\circ f^{-1}\right)'\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{g'\left(x\right)}{f'\left(x\right)}$$

Substitute $f^{-1}(x)$ for $x$ to achieve on base of $f\circ f^{-1}=\operatorname{id}$: $$\left(g\circ f^{-1}\right)'\left(x\right)=\frac{g'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)}{f'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)}$$